# How to retain least recent record in Hive?

Tags: hive

I have a logic through which I am joining multiple hive tables to generate the below output.

However, I need some help.  For the same Status ID (i.e 5 or 17), I just want to retain the record with least value of Ser NO.

But, also the catch here is,  if the Status ID repeats after status updates, (for example, Status ID 17 has come again at record 13 - that should be retained as it has again got to re-initiated and came back).

So, if I sort by date and time and status and delete the duplicates, it will not serve my purpose.

I need to put a loop and check if the Status ID has changed compared to previous record and filter out records if status ID is the same.

Expected Output should be :

```
    Ser_NO   ID    ID_NO    STATUS  DESCRIPTION             initiated_dt    time
    1        100    10      5       Initiated               20180426        000601
    3        100    10      15      BM(O) review            20180426        021424
    4        100    10      17    BM(O) & SME Review        20180426        021552
    7        100    10      40  Pending BSDA First Approval 20180426        021810
    8        100    10      25  Pending Controller approval 20180426        021844
    9        100    10      55  Booking SDA Completed       20180426        021917
    11       100    10      4   Re-Initiated                20180426        021944
    12       100    10      15  BM(O) review                20180426        030648
    13       100    10      17  BM(O) & SME Review          20180426        030714
    14       100    10      40  Pending BSDA First Approval 20180426        030734
    16       100    10      25  Pending Controller approval 20180426    030805
    17       100    10      55  Booking SDA Completed       20180426    030837
    24       100    10      60  Shipping SDA Completed      20180426    031056
    25       100    10      55  Booking SDA Completed       20180426    031124
```

But I want to know if there is any simpler approach to achieve this ?

```
Ser_NO   ID    ID_NO    STATUS  DESCRIPTION             initiated_dt    time
1        100    10      5       Initiated               20180426        000601
2        100    10      5       Initiated               20180426        021408
3        100    10      15      BM(O) review            20180426        021424
4        100    10      17    BM(O) & SME Review        20180426        021552
5        100    10      17    BM(O) & SME Review        20180426        021621
6        100    10      17    BM(O) & SME Review        20180426        021639
7        100    10      40  Pending BSDA First Approval 20180426        021810
8        100    10      25  Pending Controller approval 20180426        021844
9        100    10      55  Booking SDA Completed       20180426        021917
10       100    10      55  Booking SDA Completed       20180426        021917
11       100    10      4   Re-Initiated                20180426        021944
12       100    10      15  BM(O) review                20180426        030648
13       100    10      17  BM(O) & SME Review          20180426        030714
14       100    10      40  Pending BSDA First Approval 20180426        030734
15       100    10      40  Pending BSDA First Approval 20180426    030805
16       100    10      25  Pending Controller approval 20180426    030805
17       100    10      55  Booking SDA Completed       20180426    030837
18       100    10      55  Booking SDA Completed       20180426    030837
24       100    10      60  Shipping SDA Completed      20180426    031056
25       100    10      55  Booking SDA Completed       20180426    031124
```

Comment: And please provide desired output

Comment: Interesting question, but provide the output from the given input.

Comment: I have added the expected output also.  Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone please help on fixing this issue?